Double chalcogenide vs -ate complex salt in nomenclature
According to this post, and of course the IUPAC, one should name double salts in alphabetical order of cations followed by the anion, but when referring to double chalcogenides most of then have an analogue oxygen compound, for example the barium zirconium sulfide ($\ce{BaZrS3}$) has the related barium zirconate ($\ce{BaZrO3}$) as it's oxide analog.
Also in organic chemistry we often use the prefix "thio" when naming chains where the sulfur replaces the oxygen atom.
So my question is, can I call $\ce{BaZrS3}$ as a barium thiozirconate? Is it correct?
If so, can I expand this nomenclature to include all compounds of the form $\ce{ABX3}$ where $\ce{X} = \ce{S, Se, Te}$?

This zirconate thing is outdated.

@Mithoron if the "ate" sufix is outdated, how does one goes in distinguishing orthotitanates from metatitanates, for example $\ce{Ba2TiO4}$ and $\ce{BaTiO3}$, both would be called Barium Titanium Oxide, wouldn't?

The salts in question are not double salts, but they are complexes. Double salts when dissolved in water dissociates into two salts, while complexes dissociates into anions, in this case $\ce{Ba^2+}$ and $\ce{TiO3^-}$.
That being said, the anion is an oxyanion, and oxyanion end with -ate.  So the first example can be called barium titanate. The second example is a proper example of ternary metal chalcogenide. As it contains an sulfide, the name would be barium titanium sulfide.
But do note that the first example is still a TMC as well. So, technically the name should be barium titanium oxide. The name has been used in this paper.

this still does not solve the problem of conflicting names for different structures, e.g. $\ce{BaTiS3}$, $\ce{Ba2TiS4}$ and $\ce{Ba3TiS5}$ are all reported to exist, and following the TMC standard you've mentioned, all of them would be called Barium Titanium Sulfide.
